# Xcode assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported?

Tags: c++, xcode

Why am I getting this error message? On my old compiler it compiles fine but on my new compiler it gives me an error:

> error: assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported

The code it points to is this line:

```
*((PWORD)pbyTmp)++ = (WORD)(((a_pw[0][i] * a_dX[0]) + (a_pw[1][i] * a_dX[1])) * a_dY[0] + 0.5);
```

Comment: What is your old compiler and what is your new one?

Answer (score 1):

Your "new compiler" is correct. This is not valid C++.

The cast to `(PWORD)` creates a temporary and results in an *rvalue* expression, to which you shall not assign anything; the operator `++` assigns something.

Put a nice, friendly, *lvalue* expression (i.e. a named variable) on the left-hand-side of the assignment.

Comment: The dereference creates _lvalue_ again, so the assignment is valid. As correctly noted by ecatmur, it's the post-increment that isn't.

Comment: That's ... true. However I still think the compiler is throwing away the program for _this_ reason, based on the text of the error message. Perhaps it's being non-compliant, then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Presumably, the "assignment" it's complaining about is the `++` (applied to the *rvalue* resulting from the cast), not the `=` (applied to the *lvalue* from the pointer dereference).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the (syntactic) assignment; it's the postincrement (which of course includes assignment in its semantics).

It's possible that the intended effect of the code is:

```
*((PWORD)(pbyTmp++)) = ...
```

that is, moving the postincrement inside the cast expression.

On the other hand, your old compiler *may* be discarding the postincrement, leading to:

```
*((PWORD)pbyTmp) = ...
```

To tell which of these is intended and correct, you'll have to either sufficiently understand the intent of the code (which is non-obvious from the fragment you've provided), or inspect the assembly output of the old compiler to see how it interpreted the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
((PWORD)pbyTmp)++
```

You may hope that this increments `pbyTmp` to point at the next `WORD`. Instead, the increment would be applied to a temporary object resulting from the conversion, leaving `pbyTmp` unchanged. However, to prevent subtle bugs from mistakes like this, the language doesn't allow temporaries to be used where *lvalues* are required, hence the error.

Presumably, your older compiler didn't diagnose the error correctly, and gave some kind of undefined behaviour instead.

You should instead put the converted pointer into a variable of the correct type:

```
PWORD * pword = reinterpret_cast<PWORD>(pbyTmp);
*pword++ = whatever;
pbyTmp = reinterpret_cast<WHATEVER_pbyTMP_IS>(pword);
```

or, if you really hate whoever will have to maintain your code, cast to a (*lvalue*) reference:

```
*((PWORD&)pbyTmp)++ = whatever;
```

or, better still, change the type of `pbyTmp` to the correct type for what it points to.